The unit vectors of $l^1$ converges weakly

Let denote $\forall n \in \Bbb{N} : e_n = (0, \dots, 0, 1^{n)}, 0, \dots ) \in l^1$ . Then $e_n$ converges weakly in $l^1$, that is, for some $x \in l^1$ and for all $f \in (l^1)'$ it has that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(e_n) = f(x) $ .

I am trying to prove this excercise of my Functional analysis book . My approach consists on fix $f \in (l^1)' \setminus \{ 0_{(l^1)'} \}$ and notice that since $f: l^1 \rightarrow \Bbb{K}$ is linear, then $l^1 / \ker f \cong \Bbb{K}$ and then $\dim l^1 / \ker f = 1 $, so $\ker f$ has to be infinite dimensional. Then: $$\exists n_0 \in \Bbb{N} \, \forall n \geq n_0 : e_n \in \ker f \implies \forall n \geq n_0 : f(e_n) = 0 \implies \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(e_n) = 0 $$
Is this fine? I think that the infinite dimension of $\ker f$ it justified by this post I wrote a few days ago, but I am not sure.

This is false. Do you know that $(\ell^{1})'=\ell^{\infty}$.

I know it, but why this implies that my idea is false?

A direct counterexample to your claim would be the functional $f(a)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ which corresponds to the element $(1,1,1,\ldots)\in \ell^\infty$.

In fact, $\ell^1$ has the peculiar property that every sequence that converges weakly must converge strongly (Schur's property).

@Pengin I see, you are right, thanks!

@MaoWao I see, that is very useful, thanks!

They converge not weakly but in weak*.

Define $f(a_j)=\sum_j (-1)^{j}a_j$. Then $f$ is a continuous linear functional on $\ell^{1}$ and $f(e_n)=(-1)^{n}$ for all $n$. Since $f(e_n)$ does not have a limit it follows that $(e_n)$ does not converge weakly to any limit.

A great counterexample, thanks for your answer!

To add @geetha290krm's answer, here is a theory-heavier answer:
The sequence $(e_n)$ is a Schauder basis for $\ell_1$. Moreover, it is a boundedly complete basis, as one readily checks. Asking that $\lim f(e_n)=0$ (which is the only possible limit for $(e_n)$) for
any $f\in \ell_1'$ is equivalent to asking that $(e_n)$ is a shrinking Schauder basis fror $\ell_1'$. Now, James proved that a Banach space has a completely bounded shrinking basis if and only if it is reflective and since $\ell_1$ is not reflective, we have our contradiction.
Notice however that it the sequence $(e_n)$ is converging to $0$ in the $w^*-$topology induced by the dual pairing $c_0'=\ell_1$. This is a particular case of a more general result, due to Joseffson and Nissenzweig: for every infinite dimensional dual Banach space $X'$, there exists a sequence of unit vectors $y_n$ converging $w^*$ to $0$.
The result is true more generally: that is, there is no shrinking basis for $L^1(X,\mu)$ (where $\mu$ is, say, a $\sigma-$finite measure such that
$X$ contains an infinite number of disjoint sets of positive measure). Indeed, a shrinking basis induces a dual Schauder basis in the dual space, which in this case is $L^\infty(X,\mu)$, a nonseparable space.
